# Какого аутентификационного провайдера я должен использовать для

Tags: c#, api, asp, graph

Я хочу подключиться к сервисам Microsoft.Graph, для этого мне надо использовать аутентификационный провайдер, но тот что я нашел InteractiveAuthenticationProvider - походит только для PublicClientApplicationBuilder, какой провайдер нужен для ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder?

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Auth;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System;

...

            string[] scopes = { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

            var clientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(_clientId)
                .WithRedirectUri("http://localhost")
                .WithClientSecret(_clientSecret)
                .Build();

            var authenticationProvider = new InteractiveAuthenticationProvider(clientApplication, scopes);

            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);

            var me = graphClient.Me.Request()
                                .GetAsync().Result;
```

Проблема в том, что InteractiveAuthenticationProvider требует переменную типа IPublicClientApplication вместо IConfidentialClientApplication, который я использую чтобы передать _clientSecret

Comment: А сейчас что, не работает? Или не компилируется? Или ошибка? Какая?

Comment: InteractiveAuthenticationProvider требует переменную типа IPublicClientApplication вместо IConfidentialClientApplication, который я использую чтобы передать _clientSecret

Comment: И снова [документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS) побеждает в этом конкурсе.

Comment: Я пробовал делать как в документации, но по непонятным причинам возвращается ошибка, где указано, что мой clientSecret не подходит, хотя должен т.к. я зарегистрировал приложение как разработчик в portal.azure. И я пытаюсь сделать так как указано в моем коде

Comment: Так показывайте тогда код, который сделан по документации, но не работает. А не вымышленный.

Comment: Хорошо, буду стараться показывать все нужное в следующий раз)